Delete messages in a telegram bot
I'm writing a telegram bot to delete spam from a channel where the bot is administrator (with permission to delete messages)
I'm doing some tests using PHP and telegram-bot-sdk 2.0
I'm able to answer to messages using the bot, but if I try to delete a specific message nothing happens, and the method always returns false
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Telegram\Bot\Api;
$client = new Api('[api key here]');
$last_update_id=0;
while(true){
    $response = $client->getUpdates(['offset'=>$last_update_id, 'timeout'=>5]);
    if (count($response)<=0) continue;
    foreach ($response as $r){

        //Get the message somebody sent
        $last_update_id=$r->getUpdateId()+1;
    $message=$r->getMessage();
        $messageId = $message['message_id'];
    $chat = $message['chat'];
    $chatId = $chat['id'];
        
        //Log to console the message received
        echo "Somebody said: ".$message['text']." with message id: ".$messageId." on chat ".$chatId."\n";
        
        //Answering works
        $ret = $client->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chatId, 'text' => 'I'm deleting your message!']);
    
        //Deleting doesn't work
    $ret = $client->deleteMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chatId, 'message_id' => $messageId]);
    echo "ret:".($ret?"true":"false");
    }
}

Any Advice?
I'm not even 100% sure  deleteMessage() is a method of $client (according the documentation it seems so, but it's not totally clear) because if it mispell the method on purposes like deleteMessagx() I get false and no error.

If attempting to call arbitrary method names does not throw a PHP error, that this method does not exist - then apparently this client must have the __call() magic method implemented. https://telegram-bot-sdk.com/docs/guides/available-methods-examples says, "The library supports all the methods listed on Telegram Bot API docs page."

deleteMessage appears to exist as a "updating messages" method. What restrictions apply, is also mentioned there.
